# VBA code to generate report of blank cell in different sheet

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, macros

Hi how i can modify below code so all blank cells value are generated as report in different sheet , taken this code from my different post which i posted earlier ! but found it will end if it find first cell blank so how to loop all and make it as report in different excel

```
Sub Loop_Column_Row()
    
    Dim lRow, lCol As Long
    
    'Find the last non-blank cell in row 1
    'This assumes that the first row has column headers
    lCol = Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
    
    'Loop through columns
    For x = 1 To lCol
        'Find the last non-blank cell in the column
        lRow = Cells(Rows.Count, x).End(xlUp).Row
    
        'Loop through rows
        'Start from row 2 as row 1 is the row with headers
        For y = 2 To lRow
            If Cells(y, x) = "" Then
                'Display message box when empty cell is found
                MsgBox "Cell in Row: " & y & " Column: " & x & " is empty"
                'Stop executing the method when 1st empty cell found
                Exit Sub
            End If
        Next y
    Next x
  
End Sub
```

Comment: What do you mean by "all blank cells value are generated as report in different sheet "? Values of blank cells are blank. What do you want to copy exactly? To prevent the code from ending during the loop, you need to remove `Exit Sub`.

Comment: i want to copy "Cell in Row: " & y & " Column: " & x & " is empty" this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To prevent the code from stopping after the first blank cell is found, you need to remove `Exit Sub`. You need to have a counter that will be incremented after a blank cell is found and the message written on a cell on the report sheet (in my code below, the report sheet is Sheet3).

Your code will look like the below. `i` is the counter. I have removed the message box. But if it is important, just restore that line of code.

```
Sub Loop_Column_Row()
    
    Dim lRow, lCol As Long

    'Counter
    Dim i As Integer
    'Find the last non-blank cell in row 1
    'This assumes that the first row has column headers
    lCol = Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
    i = 1
    
    'Loop through columns
    For x = 1 To lCol
        'Find the last non-blank cell in the column
        lRow = Cells(Rows.Count, x).End(xlUp).Row
    
        'Loop through rows
        'Start from row 2 as row 1 is the row with headers
        For y = 2 To lRow
            If Cells(y, x) = "" Then
                'Write in column A of Sheet3
                ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet3").Range("A" & i).Value = "Cell in Row: " & y & " Column: " & x & " is empty"
                i = i + 1
            End If
        Next y
    Next x
  
End Sub
```

Comment: is it possible in place Column: " & x & " we can add column name A , B ,C,D,E?

Comment: @kumar Change `x` with `Chr(64 + x)` to display the column name?